# C#: What is System.Configuration.Configuration looking for?

Tags: c#

I have the following test method:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestHarvestMethod()
{
    HarvestTargetTimeRangeUTC time = new HarvestTargetTimeRangeUTC();
    time.StartTimeUTC = new DateTime(2008, 01, 01, 00, 00, 00, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    time.EndTimeUTC = DateTime.UtcNow;
    XElement lIntelexReport = XElement.Parse(rawXml);
    Harvester target = new Harvester();
    target.ConfigureHarvester((System.Configuration.Configuration)null);  
    var res = target.Harvest(time);
    Console.WriteLine(res);
 }
```

That works in conjunction with this method:

```
public void ConfigureHarvester(System.Configuration.Configuration configuration)
{
    reportId = Int32.Parse(configuration.AppSettings.Settings["IncidentReport"].Value);
}
```

to test this method:

```
public XElement Harvest(HarvestTargetTimeRangeUTC ranges)
{
    XElement lIntelexReport = IntelexServiceCall();  
    return XMLConversion(QueryData(ranges, lIntelexReport));
}
```

The problem is that I receive Null Exception error stating that "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."  on this line:

```
reportId = Int32.Parse(configuration.AppSettings.Settings["IncidentReport"].Value);
```

which I am almost positive is caused by the null value here:

```
target.ConfigureHarvester((System.Configuration.Configuration)null);
```

The System.Configuration in the above line is one used commonly in this shop, but normally for a method such as this:

```
public void ConfigureHarvester(System.Configuration.Configuration configuration)
{
    context = new PlannedOutageFactorDataContext();            
}
```

So my reportid field is obviously looking for something other than a null value, the problem is I don't know exactly WHAT it's looking for.  Ive read the MSDN for System.Configuration but it was really no help.  I would appreciate it if some one could point me in the right direction.

Comment: You are passing a `null` to the function. What do you expect?

Comment: The last code sample isn't even using the passed in `configuration` argument. Since it isn't being used, it doesn't matter what it is.

Comment: What is System.Configuration.Configuration looking for? The answer is: It is looking for a config file. Add an app.config to your test project and add the appsettings section with IncidentReport value

Comment: @Oded I understand that I am passing a null, and I know it needs to be changed.  What I do not know kind of data it is looking for.

Comment: @Esen - It is being passed in - it is not clear how it gets instantiated.

Comment: @Esen thank you.  That is exactly the direction I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its looking for you to pass it a copy of your web.config or app.config value so it can extract the information it requires from this (held in the AppSettings section)

For example

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="IncidentReport" value="1" />
    </appSettings> 
</configuration>
```

If your testing a webpage, a lot of the time you need to set the location of the webservice so that it can grab a copy of the web.config from your website.

If your developing a console/desktop app then make sure you have an app.config file

Alternativly you can manually pass it in using

```
System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(exePath);
```

Comment: +1 Change the key name to `IncidentReport` so it becomes more relevant to the question.

Comment: and an int value as Robb has suggested then you should get the tick :)

Comment: @JohnMitchell Thank you for your help. I understand now.  This is the first time I have done anything with System.Configuration and although I read the MSDN it just served to confuse me more.

Answer (score 2):

In your test assembly you'll need to have a app.config file.  Within this file you'll need a key named 'IncidentReport" with an integer value.